# Matlab OOP - Overloading size()

Tags: matlab, oop, overloading

I want to overload the `size()` function for one of my classes so that it doesn't return the object's size but rather the size of a specific member. The problem is that Matlab calls obj.size in the class constructor in order to determine the object array size.

For example:

```
classdef dataClass < handle

properties
    memberVar
end

methods 
    function obj = dataClass(mvIn)
        if nargin ~= 0
            if ~ismatrix(mvIn)
                error('Input must be a matrix');
            end

            obj.memberVar = mvIn;
        end
    end

    function sz = size(obj, varargin)
        h = @(x)builtin('size', x, varargin{:});
        sz = cell2mat(cellfun(h, {obj.memberVar}', 'uni', 0));
    end       
end

end
```

does not work because the size of the object array is made the same size as memberVar

```
a = dataClass(ones(100))

a = 

  100x100 dataClass array with properties:

  memberVar: [100x100 double]
```

A workaround is to implement the overload as

```
function sz = size(obj, varargin)
    idx = strcmpi(varargin, 'mv');
    if any(idx)
        varargin = varargin(~idx);
        h = @(x)builtin('size', x, varargin{:});
        sz = cell2mat(cellfun(h, {obj.memberVar}', 'uni', 0));
    else
        sz = builtin('size', obj, varargin{:});
    end
end
```

and call `size(obj, 'mv')` but that defeats the whole purpose of the overload, because I want to call `size()` as I would for any other object.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried dependent property? declare a dependent, SetAccess = private property `size` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be extremely careful if you want to overload `size` for a class - that's careful both in how you implement things, and careful in your design of exactly how you want the class to behave.

First, note that there's a decision to be made in whether you would like to be able to make arrays of your `dataClass` objects, or whether you are OK with only ever making scalar `dataClass` objects. If you want to be able to make arrays of `dataClass` objects, what exactly do you want `size` to do when given such an array? Do you want it to report the size of the array, or the size of the data within one `dataClass`? Which `dataClass`? Do you want it to switch behaviours when it is called on a scalar and on an array? That's going to get confusing fast.

So first of all, I would suggest that if you want to overload `size`, you'll probably want to restrict your class so that it's not possible to work with anything other than scalars. You can do this by overloading `cat`, `horzcat` and `vertcat`, and having them error (carefully, under exactly the right circumstances).

In addition to that, you need to be careful to ensure that you overload not only `size`, but also `numel`. `size` and `numel` interact in some non-obvious ways.

So with that said, you should be able to implement something like this:

```
classdef dataClass < handle

properties
    memberVar
end

methods 
    function obj = dataClass(mvIn)
        if nargin ~= 0
            if ~ismatrix(mvIn)
                error('Input must be a matrix');
            end

            obj.memberVar = mvIn;
        end
    end

    function sz = size(obj, varargin)
        sz = builtin('size', obj.memberVar, varargin{:});
    end       
end

end
```

If you also overloaded `cat`, `horzcat`, `vertcat` and `numel` as suggested above, I think this does what you're asking for.

However, there's another thing to be careful of. You mention that MATLAB calls `size` in the object constructor to determine its size. That's not actually the case - what is happening is that after you construct it, MATLAB displays the result at the command line and to do so calls `disp`, which then calls `size` to determine the size. It reports it as a 100x100 array of `dataClass`, which is not the case - it's a 1x1 array with a 100x100 `memberVar`. You can test this by trying to access `a(2)`, which will error.

So you *also* then need to overload the display methods for the class. You can do this either by inheriting your class from `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay`, or by directly overloading the methods `disp` and/or `display`. Make them display whatever you want, such as the contents of `memberVar`.

Note one last thing: in the Workspace Browser, a is reported as being 100x100 - this is again the output of `size`. I hope you're OK with that, as there's no way I know of to have size report one thing to the command line and another to the Workspace Browser.

I hope that helps - as you can see, there's a lot to think about when overloading `size`, which is why it's not typically recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware that it's actually `disp` and the workspace browser that create the confusion. I actually want to have arrays of this class, although only 1D ones... so I determine the size of the array with `numel` and the size of the member variable(s) with `size`. The important thing is that those two work and it seems they do the way I want.